# Disable default input margin / position input bottom border on text baseline

Tags: css

Is it possible to disable bottom margin for input?

[image]

I need that word was right on the line.

HTML snippet:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" class="myform" value="somet text">
</form>
```

CSS snippet:

```
form {
  background: #000;
  height: 240px;
  width: 480px;
}
.myform {
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: What is the HTML and CSS you have so far?

Comment: Please as the CSS code you are using to generate the shown example because without code it's hard to guess what the problem is exactly. Where is the underline coming from, is it a backround image or border?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2oqhytxe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not solve it with the default border-bottom line of the input element.

A possible solution could be: Fake the line with a white 1x1 pixel png and use it as a background image for the input field. You can adjust the `background-position` to have the line fitting the text baseline.

```
input.myform {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("1x1.png"); /* Insert path to the image */
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0px 20px; /* Edit to fit the text baseline */
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

That's probably not the best way so other possible solutions are welcome!